# PIG Script for processing raw data

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am doing pig processing on my raw data to make some structure out of it.

Here's the sample data:

```
Nov 1   18:23:34    dev_id=03   user_id=0123    int_ip=198.0.13.24 response_code=5
```

Expected output:

```
(Nov 1 18:23:34, 03, 0123, 198.0.12.24, 5)
```

I am trying to CONCAT(month,day,time) and remove the information before "=". I am using following script:

```
A = LOAD '----' using PigStorage('\t') as (m: chararray, d: chararray, t: chararray, devid: chararray, userid: chararray, intip: chararray, response: chararray);

B = foreach A generate CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(mnth, ' '), day), ' '), time);

C = foreach A generate REGEX_EXTRACT(devid, '^.*=(.*)$', 1),REGEX_EXTRACT(userid, '^.*=(.*)$', 1), REGEX_EXTRACT(intip, '^.*=(.*)$', 1),REGEX_EXTRACT(response, '^.*=(.*)$', 1);  

Dump B; Dump C;
```

Output:

(Nov 1 18:23:34)

(03, 0123, 198.0.12.24, 5)

Suggestion I need:

1. Can I merge, Union, and join (B, C) to achieve expected output? As there is no common field, how can we do that.
2. Is there any other way to optimize the script or different procedure to get expected output using Map-Reduce program.

Looking forward to reply, your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need two separated B and C? You could have used one foreach to output the result that you expect.

Comment: @zsxwing B used to stored the result for (mnth,day,time) formatting and C used for Regular Expression. Please correct me if i am wrong, one foreach to output results means nested foreach statement to achieve the result? can we merge both B and C operation in single statement.

Comment: What happens if you use `B = foreach A generate CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(mnth, ' '), day), ' '), time), REGEX_EXTRACT(devid, '^.*=(.*)$', 1),REGEX_EXTRACT(userid, '^.*=(.*)$', 1), REGEX_EXTRACT(intip, '^.*=(.*)$', 1),REGEX_EXTRACT(response, '^.*=(.*)$', 1);`?

Comment: Earlier I tried got Blank output as ( , , , , , ), might be some mistake in expression. Now again I tried got expected output. As I am using that script for small raw text, if I use for huge raw log file. is there any way to optimise it ?

Comment: `StringConcat(mnth, ' ', day, ' ', time)` is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you problem was in delimiters. You specify \t as delimiter (though this is the default), but you input data has spaces between fields.

Here is the code that works:

```
$ cat input
Nov 1   18:23:34    dev_id=03   user_id=0123    int_ip=198.0.13.24  response_code=5

$ cat script.pig
A = LOAD 'input' as (mnth: chararray, day: chararray, time: chararray, devid: chararray, userid: chararray, intip: chararray, response: chararray);

B = foreach A generate CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(mnth, ' '), day), ' '), time),
REGEX_EXTRACT(devid, '^.*=(.*)$', 1),
REGEX_EXTRACT(userid, '^.*=(.*)$', 1),
REGEX_EXTRACT(intip, '^.*=(.*)$', 1),
REGEX_EXTRACT(response, '^.*=(.*)$', 1);  

DUMP B;

$ pig -x local script.pig
...log messages...
(Nov 1 18:23:34,03,0123,198.0.13.24,5)
```

Hope that helps.